# Shortest path from one to many points to return path id's using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shortest-path, network-analysis

I'm trying to find the shortest path between many points (pink) and one point (light green) using a network of lines (dark green). For each path found I need the list of line id's that make that path.

[image]

I have been using the inbuilt network analysis tool 'shortest path (layer to point)' and it returns the 'cost' for each path I need the id's making that path instead of the cost.

How do I do this using QGIS?